# Symfony2 Doctrine, How to fetch only the column names of particular table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi i want only the table field names(column names) how to achieve that, as of now i do have the following code -

```
$em        =   $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$entities  =   $em->getRepository('SkerpInventoryBundle:InventoryMaster')->findAllIndex();
```

I am using the repositories to fetch all the data of the table. Now in "$entities" I am having the result data. Can anyone let me know how to fetch only the field name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess, this is what you need (assume that you are in your controller):

```
    $mappings = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getClassMetadata('AcmeBundle:SomeEntity');
    $fieldNames = $mappings->getFieldNames();
```

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. can you please let me know how to accept the answer

Answer (score -6):

You can use DQL (Doctrine Query Language) For this. For example:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.username FROM CmsUser u');
$users = $query->getResults(); // array of CmsUser username values
echo $users[0]['username'];
```

For more information on DQL see:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: That's not how you receive the column names.